Quarkus update never ending
I'm trying to update a quarkus project with quarkus update but it nevers ends.
I used -e --verbose parameters but don't get any errors or hints.
It displays

[INFO] Not parsing quark C:\dev\projets\CheckPoint~.m2\repository\org\hibernate\orm\hibernate-core\6.4.8.Final\hibernate-core-6.4.8.Final.jar as its size 11 MB exceeds size threshold 10 MB

And gets stuck there without ending.
My project version is 3.8.5. I tried to update with -stream=3.8 to update to 3.8.6 and -stream=3.15 to update to latest LTS, but none of them work.
Does anyone encountered such behaviour ?
What can I do to make it work ?

Is your .m2/ in the project you are trying to update? From the message, it looks like OpenRewrite is trying to parse the .m2/ content which looks very odd.
If it's the case, I think I would try by moving the .m2 out and see how it goes.
If it works, I'm not entirely sure how we could handle this use case from the OpenRewrite standpoint but I can ask there if they have some advices.

My .m2/ is in a custom path, configured in a custom settings.xml, automatically loaded by IntelliJ usually.
To launch the update I used the console and thus not loaded the settings.xml.
I don't know why, but Maven created the .m2/ in my project.
By adding the path to my settings.xml file with my custom path to my .m2/ it worked.
Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.
